# Using a library linked in a bootloader within an application flashed by that bootloader

Tags: c, linker, embedded, shared-libraries, bootloader

I am developing a bootloader for an embedded system using adapted GCC toolchain that only supports C. The purpose of the bootloader is flashing an application code and verifying its integrity on boot. Both the bootloader and the application communicate over the same protocol. The platform provides libraries for communicating via this protocol.

Trivially both the bootloader and the application would contain said library, however due to possible flash storage space constraints (depending on resulting bootloader code size) I consider including the library only in the bootloader and letting the application use the library from the bootloader.

I am aware of solutions that require extra work from the application side like setting function pointers at the beginning of the application based on some address the bootloader saved in some agreed place. However since the application is already at a certain stage of development I want to avoid altering it to much or ideally not at all.

I am looking for a solution where I can tell the linker of the application which functions don't need to be linked in the binary and set the correct address in the bootloader address space. How can I achieve that?

Also both bootloader and application have their own interrupt vector tables. During execution of the bootloader possible interrupts of the library would work with bootloader's table. When the execution is passed to the application is it possible that the fact of the library being in bootloader's address space would somehow lock it to the interrupt vector table of the bootloader?

Comment: Your question has multiple issues to look at in detail, and unfortunately I don't have the time to dissect them.

Comment: 1) There are already questions and answers on the same topic. Please do some research.

Comment: 2) You can provide a linker script that resolves references to library functions with the actual addresses in the bootloader. This is fragile, as any change of the bootloader possibly changes these addresses. Consider to use a vector table or jump table at a fixed address.

Comment: 3) When realizing the proposal of point 2, consider to separate the library from both the bootloader and the application.

Comment: 4) Yes, without any other change, interrupts will vector to the bootloader's ISR. However, some MCUs using a interrupt vector table (you did not provide which MCU you use) have options to change the base address of the table.

Comment: @thebusybee 2) with a vector/jump table I would need to replace any calls to the library in the application to regard the new calling strategy. That seems error prone as well since the application already exist. I was hoping I can extract symbols from the bootloader and include them during linkage of the application. This wouldn't be a problem since even if the bootloader would be flashed again, the application would be flashed as well. 3) I thought about it but couldn't find anything about said separation. How would I do that? Do you have some references? 4) It's the MLX81882.

Comment: Write a replacement library that jumps to the vectors, and link bootloader and application to that. There is no need to change their source code. However, you need a third "application" that provides the vectors/jumps and the library functions.

Comment: A quick web search reveals no hit for "MLX81882". Please add a link to its user manual or data sheet by [edit]ing your question.